# Missing data from JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, image, blob

In an API, I am trying to pass some images as raw data with some other info. in a json response. E.g.

```
[{img:…………,data:a},
{img:………,color:red},
{img:………,dumb:1}]
```

The data of the images is in raw byte which is uploaded previously with blobs in a form.
With

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
...
xhr.onreadystate = function(){
  …
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  for (let obj of data) {
    console.log(obj.img.length);
  }
  …
}
...
xhr.send()
```

I found that there is data lost during the process. The `length` of the images data is smaller comparing if I use `fetch` with `arrayBuffer()`. E.g

```js
var data = await fetch(url).(res)=>{return res.arrayBuffer();}};
Console.log(data);
```

It is possible to reconstruct all the images from 3 individual fetch but failed from the json response.
What's wrong with `JSON.parse()` that it removes the data? Is that something related to the raw data represented in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not supporting binary data by default. You can use some workarounds though like escaping it with `base64` but it adds some overhead to the request size.

Comment: I have tried to base64 encode the binary from the server and get the correct data size in the client. However, `atob()` produces  totally different result.